# array output of number more than 14 chars

Tags: php, arrays, facebook

i'm  using facebook fql to get some data , these data are in array
when i use json to decode the result it gives me users id in that style

```
$result = json_decode($result, true);

the result from array is 1.0000148607246E+14
```

instead of `10000148607246` 
i know its the same number but when i use that result to get new data from facebook "request back" it gives me error with id

the question now is how to convert `1.0000148607246E+14` to `10000148607246` in php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the `precision` setting on to the top of the PHP tag.

```
<?php
echo $var=1.0000148607246E+14; //"prints" 1.0000148607246E+14
ini_set('precision', 18); // <------------------ Add this on to the top of your code
echo $var=1.0000148607246E+14; //"prints" 1.0000148607246
```

Answer (score 0):

```
number_format(1.0000148607246E+14,0,'','');
```

You can read more [here](https://www.php.net/number_format)

**Output**

```
100001486072460
```